# Android date format parse throwing an Unhandled Exception

Tags: java, android, date

I'm storing dates in a database as a single `string` in the format "2 15 2015" (presumably "M d yyyy"?).  `strDate` in the code below contains the return value of a method that grabs the date.  I want to parse the date so as to set a `datepicker`. Based on the examples in [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

I've created the following code for parsing the date, but am getting an "`Unhandled Exception: java.text.ParseException`" at

```
Date date = format.parse(strDate);
```

Scratching my head.

```
Calendar mydate = new GregorianCalendar();
String strDate = datasource.get_Column_StrVal(dbData,
        MySQLiteHelper.dbFields.COLUMN_SPECIAL_DAYS_DATE);
SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("M d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(strDate);
mydate.setTime(date);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this compile-time error because you are not handling the `ParseException` that the `parse` method throws. This is necessary because `ParseException` is not a runtime exception (it is a checked exception since it extends directly from `java.lang.Exception`).

You need to surround your code with try/catch to handle the exception, like this :

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat  format = new SimpleDateFormat("M d yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date date = format.parse(strDate);
    mydate.setTime(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    //handle exception
}
```

Comment: That worked.  It seems odd that the try catch is required.  Do you recommend anything in the  "//handle exception" line?

Comment: `ParseException` is a checked exception. You either need to catch it or declare that your method can throw it (using `throws` clause). Handling the exception should answer the question "what should I do if a date is incorrect in DB ?". You probably need to log it at least.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you indeed have it. Just surround it with try/catch as the compiler will hint you.